# Alternatives of template classes in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to a define generic classes without using templates in C++. I have written a compiler for a language which generates C++ code but I haven't included template construct in my language.

What I want to know is it possible to generic classes in my language with my language as well.

The tried to do it by the following way:

For implementing a new data structure (eg. stack) I declare its type as “Data”, an empty class, and imposed a restriction on the user to first define a new class (eg. myData) which extends Data and use only myData objects with the data structure.

Stack.h definition:

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

#include <stack>

class Data{};

class Stack {
private:
    std::stack<Data*> st;
public:
    bool empty()    {return st.empty();}
    int size()  {return st.size();}
    void pop()  {st.pop();}
    Data* top() {return st.top();}
    void push(Data &e) {st.push(&e); }
};

#endif
```

Expected definition of “myData” from user:

```
class myData: public Data{
public:
    int a;
    myData (int A): a(A){}
    myData (){}
    myData (const Data& x) {
    }

    myData& operator= (const Data& x) {
    }
    int getData(){return a;}
};
```

Tried to run the following main():

```
int main(){
    stack<Data*> st;
    myData A(10);
    st.push(&A);
    printf("%u\n", &A);
    printf("Size: %d\n", (int)st.size());

    myData B;
    Data *C = (st.top());
    B = *((myData*)C);
    printf("%u\n", C);
    printf("%d\n", B.getData());

    return 0;
}
```

I want to know is there any better apporoach to try do the same which is more organized and proper. You can assume my language to be (c++ - {template classes}).

Comment: You can see what are done in other language : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming

Comment: Yes, there are other mechanisms to provide genericity, and you've presented one yourself. However, this question is of little value because it's essentially "what could C++ do instead in this regard" which is unlikely to reach any constructive answers. Hence VTC.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like there are no alternatives of templates in C++ that's why they have been included as a basic feature in the language.

Comment: There are indeed alternatives, such as Java's (paraphrased) "every class inherits from `Object`, and Generics cast to the actual type during runtime".  A similar system could be incorporated in C++ class design, but it wouldn't be nearly as efficient as templates.